# executing a shell script from a php file

Tags: php, shell

i have a php file from which i need to call a shell script which i am doing as follows:

```
$out = exec("/root/.mozilla/firefox/score.sh 2>&1");
echo $out;
```

when i execute this code in opera its giving Permission denied. I have given permission to all directory and the script also.

is the problem because of that .mozilla file?? how to solve??
also tried with shell_exec().. not working

Comment: this problem is only for opera?

Comment: no .. i even tried in mozilla.. same problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you given the web server user write/execute permissions?:

For example (assuming your web server user is apache belonging to group apache):

```
sudo chown apache:apache /root/.mozilla/firefox/score.sh
sudo chmod -R 744 /root/.mozilla/firefox/score.sh
```

Comment: u mean permission to the script file?? i have given 777 for that directory and to the script file. If its not what ur saying please let me know hoe to do it.

Comment: @su03: Setting `777` when it's not necessary opens up big security holes.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the webuser has permission to access all directories leading up to `/root/.mozilla/firefox/`. Ideally, you'd move this script someplace else than `root`'s homedir.