# Issue system commands from ArcGIS map

Tags: linux, shell, arcgis

I have an ArcGIS Javascript API based map hosted in linux machine. The map has many pop-ups and each pop-up in turn has a button. Is is possible to run a shell script or a system command with a click of a button in the pop-up? Thanks!

EDIT: Added code snippet!

```
            function pageReady() {
            var popup = new esri.dijit.Popup({
              fillSymbol: new esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new dojo.Color([255,0,0]), 2), new dojo.Color([255,255,0,0.25]))
            }, dojo.create("div"));


            var initExtent = new esri.geometry.Extent({"xmin":-13626637,"ymin":4550020,"xmax":-13624728,"ymax":4551042,"spatialReference":{"wkid":102100}});
            map = new esri.Map("map",{
              infoWindow:popup,
              outFields: ["*"]
            });


            dojo.addClass(map.infoWindow.domNode, "myTheme");


            dojo.connect(map,"onClick",function(evt){
              var query = new esri.tasks.Query();
              query.geometry = pointToExtent(map,evt.mapPoint,10);

              var deferred = featureLayer.selectFeatures(query,esri.layers.FeatureLayer.SELECTION_NEW);

               map.infoWindow.setFeatures([deferred]);
               map.infoWindow.show(evt.mapPoint);

            });

            var basemap = new esri.layers.ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer("http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/ESRI_Imagery_World_2D/MapServer");
            map.addLayer(basemap);
```

Ram

Comment: You mean run a shell script/command on the server? Depends on your web server I guess, it's not really specific to the ArcGIS JS API - have your button call a page on the server that kicks off the shell script....depending on what language support you have. PHP can probably do it? [linky!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882650/how-to-execute-a-shell-script-in-php).

Comment: No, the thing is, ArcGIS API has pop-up templates and I'm not sure if we can do a POST to a php or jsp page. Correct me if I'm wrong here.

Comment: By 'pop-up' do you mean the ArcGIS InfoWindow/InfoTemplate? Can you show us the code of your template? It should be just a case of hooking the onclick method of the button, and using [jQuery.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) or [dojo.xhrPost](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/xhrPost.html) to prod the php page. There's no real limitations (other than space) on what you can do inside an InfoWindow.

Comment: I have edited my post with the code. Thanks!

Comment: What server side language are you most comfortable with? Python/PHP/Java/etc?

Answer (score 0):

I used web sockets and solved this problem. Thanks everyone for your inputs!