# Linux uptime command inside php doesn't show anything

Tags: php, linux, uptime

I am trying a linux command for uptime in a php file on a server as below

```
<p> The uptime for this system is <?php $up_time=shell_exec('uptime');
echo $uptime; ?</p>
```

But when I open my webpage it just shows :

```
The uptime for this system is
```

PHP doesn't appear to be running the command.
If I go to command prompt and run uptime, I do see the results.

I am doing ssh into a Linux webserver. The php file resides in my folder on the server.

Comment: I presume you closed the `<?php` properly in your actual code, unlike in your example above?

Comment: Have you tried absolute path? /bin/uptime
Shell_exec will return null on error.

Comment: You should see this question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882650/how-to-execute-a-shell-script-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following code will work.

```
The uptime for this system is <?php passthru('/usr/bin/uptime'); ?>
```

executing system command in a php, I suggest you always provide the full path of the command.

Comment: Hi - Thanks a lot. It worked but there is a difference between what I get from the php command and what I get if I write uptime on the terminal. In php I get the following "The uptime for this system is 00:21:47 up 77 days, 9:58, 0 users, load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00" But on the terminal I get the following "00:21:42 up 755 days, 22:16,  4 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
" would you know why?

Comment: do you execute commands on the same machine? 77days <<< 755days!

Answer (score 0):

Linux server uptime can be easily obtained in PHP using the /proc/uptime

```
$uptimeseconds = (int)shell_exec('cat /proc/uptime');
echo "This server has been running for $uptimeseconds seconds.\n";
```