# Run shell script from php and see complete progress?

Tags: php, shell, ubuntu, nginx, gulp

Is there a way to run a shell script from PHP and echo the results after progress is completed?

Here is my shell script:

(Its multilines - a few commands that have to be ran one after the other. )

```
cd
cd /var/www/html/
npm uninstall gulp --save
npm install gulp --save
npm start
```

here's my currently functioning PHP script. It only outputs some of the progress and only outputs it when complete. I need a live preview of the progress.

```
    <?php
echo "loaded<br><br>";
 // echo shell_exec("cd /var/www/html/..");
// rin the shell scrip from header_register_callback
echo '<pre>';
// Outputs all the result of shellcommand "ls", and returns
// the last output line into $last_line. Stores the return value
// of the shell command in $retval.
$last_line = system('cd /var/www/html/; npm start', $retval);
// Printing additional info
echo '
</pre>
<hr />Last line of the output: ' . $last_line . '
<hr />Return value: ' . $retval;
?>
```

Comment: Given that the script would be running `npm *` scripts, the user will likely need root/sudo access, right? Is that the same user that customers will use? If so, you might want to reconsider the approach to this deployment process. There are CI tools like [jenkins](https://jenkins.io/doc/) that could be used to create a deployment script whenever you need to run those commands...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another approach. It uses [redirection](http://cecs.wright.edu/~pmateti/Courses/233/Labs/Scripting/bashVsPowerShellTable.html) to output the results and then [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to read the output.

```
<?php

echo "loaded<br><br>";

$cmd = 'npm start';
$run = $cmd . ' > result.txt 2> errors.txt';
$output = shell_exec($run);

$results = file_get_contents('result.txt');
if (strlen(file_get_contents('errors.txt')) != 0) {
  $results .= file_get_contents('errors.txt');
}

echo "<pre>$results</pre>";

?>
```

Comment: In order for @StarShows Studios to get this to work, he/she may need to put all the npm commands (e.g. `npm uninstall gulp`, `npm install gulp`, etc) into a shell script and run that script in *$cmd* in order to have the output get redirected to the txt files appropriately... also might need to set add the web user (*www-data*?) sudoers (see [the **Update** to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882650/how-to-execute-a-shell-script-in-php) for more info)

Answer (score 0):

I guess, ob_flush() would work:

```php
    <?php
echo "loaded<br><br>";
ob_flush();

 // echo shell_exec("cd /var/www/html/..");
// rin the shell scrip from header_register_callback
echo '<pre>';
ob_flush();
// Outputs all the result of shellcommand "ls", and returns
// the last output line into $last_line. Stores the return value
// of the shell command in $retval.
$last_line = system('cd /var/www/html/; npm start', $retval);
// Printing additional info
echo '
</pre>
<hr />Last line of the output: ' . $last_line . '
<hr />Return value: ' . $retval;
?>
```

But I don't understand why you echo HTML-tags when you run that script on the console... Hope I got you right