# Newbie: Where to place script for cronjob?

Tags: openshift

I'm deploying an apache container which downloads php code from my github, but this code should run every 5min because it pulls an external API and fills a database.

I've been reading about cron in openshift and do understand the scripts, but I have no clue on where to put the scripts. All examples talk about how to put the script in the following directory: ".openshift/cron/minutely/awesome_job" but where is it ?????

Should I create it on my local harddisk and use the OC client to deploy an apache cointainer from that directory? I'm lost.

Using public Paas OpenShift.

Comment: Hi! Maybe you should create your cron container follwing that tuto : https://docs.openshift.org/latest/dev_guide/cron_jobs.html .
And mount the volume you want to update into your croned container (created with the tuto). That way it'll push changes directly into your apache container

Comment: Explain me how exactly your script work, does it only trigger a new `git pull` into the git project cloned into your apache container? And i maybe could try to give you a more specific answer

Comment: When deploying Apache / PHP it pulls my application code from github. After that is done, Openshift will update when github code changes. So my application changes are all working. But part of the application has to be triggered every x minutes. That is where I need the trigger to run: #!/bin/sh
/bin/rm -f /tmp/nest_php_* ; /usr/bin/php /var/www/nest/insert.php > /dev/null

Comment: Well sounds difficult to make it with openshift's crons, wouldn't it be easier to trigger that script every 5 mins from inside your php app? Cause i don't see any other clean enough solutions here ;)

Comment: That would be nice, but I don't think PHP can do that :-)

Comment: Another way would be to expose executing that shell script on an url :
For example https://myapp.mycompany.com/awesome_job
It means you have to embed the code in you php app and create a route (if you have a router in your framework or whatever you use) for accessing it.
So when you `curl https://myapp.mycompany.com/awesome_job` it trigger the script.
Then you can create an openshift cron job that would juste curl this URL every 5mins.
Seems possible using that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882650/how-to-execute-a-shell-script-in-php. Don't you think so?

Answer (score 0):

Mine are in /etc/cron.daily/ but there are other flavors too, like .hourly, .weekly, .monthly..  This is debian.
I've also regularly put them in /usr/local.  Or in my own home directory if these are personal jobs.  Basically you give cron a path, so it goes there.

Comment: Hmmm no what I mean is: how do I get the file in the container running in the public PaaS? I now deploy an default Apache container and I can give it a source repo https://github.com/TheGabeMan/MyNew.git

But where will it find the script with the cronjob to pull into the container? I don't want to have to edit the contents of the container after deployment. Or should I say Image instead of container?